# how control code with set_time_limit on php code

Tags: php, cron, locking

I have problem in one of my project

here my sample code

- it be used as cronjob 

- exec time is 30 sec for example

- page must have execute time limit cause every time start cron, cron be lock until task finish or face the time limit on execute and call __destruct function on lockcron class

```
1 $lockcron = new lockcron("test.lock");
2 $lockcron->lockit();

3 $retdata = $samplemodel->all('rand',100); // return random limit 100
4 $webserice = $websericeobj->send($retdata);
5 $samplemodel->savewebserive($retdata,$webserivce);
```

- line 4 web service each time adjusted cost

  now, if line 1,2,3 take 20 sec and line 4 take 10sec(time can be diffrent,consider rand(1,50)), it's not run line 5, but it cost system. cause line 4 send request to webservice.

  I need solution for this situation
  one of my idea is before line 4 check how much time i have spent time for line 1,2,3 then if it's bigger than max time code need to run line 4 and 5 not run codes, but it can not be correct always cause line4 may be be biggar than max time, its not in my control

Comment: Try this `set_time_limit(60);` for the reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola thanks, but i don't need to increase time limit, cause time for all exec code can be change, today may work with 60sec, but tomorrow it may take 120 sec